# Namespace for map in Saxon-EE

Tags: xml, xpath, saxon, basex, xquery-3.0

I am trying to run the following code in saxon

`map:merge(for $mov in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie return map:entry($mov/@id, avg($mov/ratings/child::node())))`

However, I am getting the error as follows:

`XPST0081: Namespace prefix 'map' has not been declared`

I believe I need to set the namespace at the beginning of the query.

So I searched a little and found an answer [here](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Map_Module#Conventions) and modified my code as follows:

```
import module namespace map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";

map:merge(for $mov in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie return map:entry($mov/@id, avg($mov/ratings/child::node())))
```

I get another error: `XQST0059: Cannot locate module for namespace http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map`

What namespace must I use?

**UPDATE**

I tried a new code

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
map:merge(for $mov in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie return map:entry($mov/@id, avg($mov/ratings/child::node())))
```

and used the following command

`java -cp saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qversion:3.1 -o:out mapq.xq`

I get a new error as follows

```
Error on line 2 at column 28 of file:mapq.xq
  Cannot serialize a map using the xml method
Query failed with dynamic error: Cannot serialize a map using the xml method
```

Comment: The new [adaptive](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization-31/#adaptive-output) method will allow you to output maps. You can add the following lines to the prolog of your query:

declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "adaptive"; – Probably it would make more sense to discuss that in a separate StackOverflow issue.

Comment: Dear Dr. I am using the following code
`declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare namespace output = "w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "adaptive";
map:merge(for $mov in doc("movies.xml")/movies/movie return map:entry($mov/@id, avg($mov/ratings/child::node())))` Still says error

Comment: Could you please open a new issue?

Comment: @ChristianGrün I got it thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";`. Also note that outputting a map directly needs output method `adaptive` (`!method=apaptive`) or `json` I think.

As an alternative, based on Christian Grün's comment, use the prolog

```
declare namespace map = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map";
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
declare option output:method "adaptive";
```

Comment: Assuming Saxon 9.7, add `!method=adaptive` to the command line so that your map result can be serialized.

Comment: `java -cp saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qversion:3.1 !method=adaptive mapq.xq`
`java -cp saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qversion:3.1 method=adaptive mapq.xq`
Both are Not working, I am afraid

Comment: Try `java -cp saxon9ee.jar net.sf.saxon.Query -qversion:3.1 -q:mapq.xq !method=adaptive`. The serialization parameter belongs after any option as far as I remember. And `adaptive` is supported since 9.7, I don't think 9.6 supported that new serialization method.

Comment: I am using 9.7. Error is `bash: !method=adaptive: event not found`

Comment: That looks like your shell `bash` interprets the `!` instead of passing it on to the application. I don't know `bash`, someone else needs to help to tell you how to escape the parameter to Saxon in bash. On Windows with Powershell the `!method=adaptive` works fine.

Comment: In bash the "!" needs to be escaped as "\!"